# Minimum number of locks and keys

Tags: combinatorics

5 persons own a safe with a number of locks (arranged parallel, i.e. all locks must be opened to open the safe).  One lock can have any number of keys. The owners want any combination of (a minimum of) 3 persons to be able to open the safe.

I can see that one solution is to have 5!/(3!2!)=10 locks and distribute the keys according to the permutations owners. But is that also the minimum number of locks?

Edit: following new searches using the work "lock" I see that the question might be a duplicate. I see also that my own solution may be wrong according to a comment

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning at all. Please elaborate. For example if you have 4 people and at least 3 are required to open the safe, then you would claim that $\binom{4}{3}$ locks are enough, but I can prove that it is impossible.

Comment: I also think 10 locks are needed.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's a requirement that two people acting alone can never open the safe, right?

Comment: @Keith: yes - 3 is a minimum.

Comment: @user21820: I would say for persons a,b,c and d, and key K1 to lock 1 etc,  that  a and b have both K1 and K2 and b and c have both K1 and K3.

Comment: That's 3 locks, not $\binom{4}{3}$ locks as per your vague suggestion.

Comment: It should be $\binom{4}{2}$ in that case. It would take six locks.

Comment: @Keith: Yes it takes 6 locks but you can't just claim it is possible without showing how.

Comment: Each group of two people would have its own lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ten locks is the minimum number.

Given any group of two people, say A and B, they can't open the safe. That means there's some lock that only people among C, D and E have the key to. But in fact, all of C, D and E must have the key: if, for instance, C didn't have the key, then it would be impossible for A, B and C to open the safe working together.

It follows that for every group of three people, there must be a lock for which they are the key owners.

Therefore it takes $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ locks.

Edit: Conversely, we obtain a solution by having one lock for each set of three people.

Comment: I don't agree. Unless you show a particular way of distributing the keys, you cannot claim that there is a solution using 10 locks.

Comment: @user21820 I hope the edit is satisfactory.

Comment: Huh your edit doesn't make sense. You need to show that **any** group of 3 people have the keys to **all** the locks.

Comment: @user21820: I agree that Keith's edit doesn't help. But in fact $10$ locks is enough, because if $A$ and $B$ don't have a key to lock $K$, then $C, D$, and $E$ must all have it.

Comment: Yes, that's the case. Given a group of three people trying to open the safe, and any particular lock, one of the three people must be among those who have the key. There are three people who have the key, there are three people present, and there are only five people in all, so there must be someone in common between those who are present and those who have the key. This argument for sufficiency was not repeated because the same information was implicit in the necessity argument. @user21820

Comment: Alright that's correct and should go into your answer.

Comment: I think if $m$ out of $n$ people are required to open the safe, then we need $\binom{n}{m-1}$ locks.

Comment: @user21820 No, that would make the answer too long. That amounts to going back and checking that the previous necessary conditions were actually sufficient, but if you simply re-read the first part with a view to sufficiency, it will be clear that it works.

Comment: How about the general case n owners of which m must be present to open the safe, and the case above with 4 over 3?

Comment: @MikaelJensen TonyK is correct in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Each group of 2 should have one **unique** unopenable lock, 
so minimum # of locks needed =${5\choose 2}$= 10

"I" must have the missing key for each group of 2 to which I don't belong, i.e. ${4\choose2}$ = 6 keys, 
so minimum # of keys needed = 5*6 = 30

Answer (score 1):

Any group of two people should not be able to open the safe, it means that for each of the $\binom 52$ groups of two, there must be at least one key they don't own. This key must be different for any two groups of two. The minimal solution is then $\binom 52=10$. For each of the 10 groups of two, there is a key they don't possess.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been already answered in full, but since a commenter asked for an explicit solution, I will post one:

```
A     456789
B  123   789
C 0 23 56  9
D 01 34 6 8
E 012 45 7
```

Persons are named `A-E`, locks are numbered `0-9`, and, for instance, `C 0 23 56  9` means that person $C$ has a key for each of the locks in $\{0,2,3,5,6,9\}$.

It is easy to see that it’s minimal: there are three keys for each lock (arranged in columns), and if you remove one of those 30 keys, there will be a column with three spaces, and the group of three persons identified by these spaces will not be able to open the corresponding lock. If you remove one whole column, the two people identified by the spaces in the removed column will be able to open all remaining 9 locks.